# mutex unlocking and request_module() behaviour

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming

I've observed the following code pattern in the Linux kernel, for example `net/sched/act_api.c` or many other places as well :

```
rtnl_lock();
rtnetlink_rcv_msg(skb, ...);
  replay:
  ret = process_msg(skb);
    ...
    /* try to obtain symbol which is in module. */
    /* if fail, try to load the module, otherwise use the symbol */
    a = get_symbol();
    if (a == NULL) {
       rtnl_unlock();
       request_module();
       rtnl_lock();
       /* now verify that we can obtain symbols from requested module and return EAGAIN.*/
       a = get_symbol();
       module_put();
       return -EAGAIN;
    }
  ...
  if (ret == -EAGAIN)
     goto replay;
  ...
rtnl_unlock();
```

After `request_module` has succeeded, the symbol we are interested in, becomes available in kernel memory space, and we can use it. However I don't understand why return EAGAIN and re-read the symbol, why can't just continue right after `request_module()`?

Comment: Which version of the kernel sources are you looking at? The above code seems to return `-EAGAIN` while holding a lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [current implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/sched/act_api.c#L553) in the Linux kernel, there is a comment right after the 2nd call equivalent to `get_symbol()` in your above code (it is `tc_lookup_action_n()`) that explains exactly why:

```
rtnl_unlock();
request_module("act_%s", act_name);
rtnl_lock();

a_o = tc_lookup_action_n(act_name);

/* We dropped the RTNL semaphore in order to
 * perform the module load.  So, even if we
 * succeeded in loading the module we have to
 * tell the caller to replay the request.  We
 * indicate this using -EAGAIN.
 */
if (a_o != NULL) {
    err = -EAGAIN;
    goto err_mod;
}
```

Even though the module could be requested and loaded, since the semaphore was dropped in order to load the module which is an operation that can sleep (and is not the "standard way" this function is executed, the function returns `EAGAIN` to signal it.

EDIT for clarification:

If we look at the call sequence when a new action is added (which could cause a required module to be loaded) we have this sequence: `tc_ctl_action()` -> `tcf_action_add()` -> `tcf_action_init()` -> `tcf_action_init_1()`.
Now if "move back" the `EAGAIN` error back up to `tc_ctl_action()` in the `case RTM_NEWACTION:`, we see that with the `EAGAIN` ret value the call to `tcf_action_add` is repeated.

Comment: I certainly read the comment before posting my question, but I don't understand why the caller should be re-doing its request if the semaphore has been dropped. There's a small window between `rtnl_unlock` and `rtnl_lock` where another thread could be scheduled for execution, is this the reason?

Comment: Yes exactly: `rtnl_unlock()` calls `netdev_run_todo()` that explicitely make calls that can sleep. Furthermore, `request_module()` is in fact `__request_module(true, mod)` where true expresses that we wait for the module to be loaded, which is also an operation that could sleep.